# Want to adapt this code to count placed and unplaced for a pie chart in oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi i was wondering how/ where can i add a count to adjust this code to make it count placed and unplaced students so that this code can be used in APEX to make a pie chart.

```sql
SELECT programme.name 
     , CASE WHEN Current_Status = 'Applicant accepted offer' 
            THEN  'placed' 
            ELSE 'unplaced' END   AS placed
     , students.Student_first_name
     , students.student_last_name
     , students.email
     , students.CV_APPROVAL_DATE
  FROM Students
INNER 
  JOIN programme 
    ON programme.programme_id = students.programme_id
INNER 
  JOIN application 
    ON Application.SRN = students.student_record_number
 WHERE students.CV_APPROVAL_DATE IS NOT NULL
ORDER
    BY programme.name 
     , placed
```

Any help is much appreciated thanks, so far this code works and brings me the active (cv approval) students placed and unplaced but i need to add a count to get total placed and total unplaced to work within this code

Comment: Count what? If you add sample data and expected it will be much easier to understand the problem.

Comment: Hey sorry if it wasn't clear, i want to count the total number of students placed and total number unplaced. So they can be compared in a pie chart. So far this gives the all students placed and all that are unplaced although i need to somehow adapt this to be put into a pie char. so unplaced and placed need counting/totaling

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply add two sub-selects:

```
SELECT programme.name 
     , CASE WHEN Current_Status = 'Applicant accepted offer' 
            THEN  'placed' 
            ELSE 'unplaced' END   AS placed
     , students.Student_first_name
     , students.student_last_name
     , students.email
     , students.CV_APPROVAL_DATE
     , (select count(*) from Students where Current_Status = 'Applicant accepted offer') as placed_total
     , (select count(*) from Students where Current_Status <> 'Applicant accepted offer') as unplaced_total
  FROM Students
INNER 
  JOIN programme 
    ON programme.programme_id = students.programme_id
INNER 
  JOIN application 
    ON Application.SRN = students.student_record_number
 WHERE students.CV_APPROVAL_DATE IS NOT NULL
ORDER
    BY programme.name 
     , placed
```

Comment: Thanks thats great although it doesn't seem to work for a pie chart, i will have a look again. but thanks very much that seems to be along the right lines